# implementing timeout in python twisted

Tags: python, client-server, twisted

As far as I know twisted is asynchronous and event driven and someone told me their is no need for timeout. I have to build a server application which will be connected to more than 100 clients which are embedded machines sending data to server every 2 minutes and each packet or data will be of size 238 - 1500 bytes. Thus is real life case tcp will be breaking data into multiple packets so is their any need to implement timeout or twisted will handle such situation. Any advise since I am new twisted. I have following code for my server without timeout. At the end of timeout I just want to discard packet if full packet is not received while connection remains alive.

```
class Server(LineReceiver):

  def connectionMade(self):
     self.factory.clients.append(self)
     self.setRawMode()
     self._peer = self.transport.getPeer()
     print 'Connected Client', self._peer

  def connectionLost(self, reason):
     self.factory.clients.remove(self)
     print 'Lost connection from', self._peer

  def rawDataReceived(self, data):
     inputArray = [ord(inp) for inp in data]
     #do something



def main():
   """This runs the protocol on port 8000"""
   factory = protocol.ServerFactory()
   factory.protocol = Server
   factory.clients = []
   reactor.listenTCP(8000,factory)
   reactor.run()
```

Comment: Make a function which does the connection cuts. In the main function, keep a track of time(s), when it is time, trigger that function(s)?

Comment: Did you try to send data of size `238 - 1500 bytes` ? What were the outcomes?

Comment: I created a similar application in c# and tested without timeouts I was able to receive complete packets but it was tested with 2-3 clients only but if their more than 100-1000 clients sending data every 2 minutes then I think their is a need for timeout. Maybe I am wrong? correct me.

Comment: why do you use `LineReceiver` instead of `Protocol`? Is there line-oriented data in the begining e.g., such as in http protocol (headers are line-oriented, body can be anything)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Ashish Nitin Patil suggested, just cut the connection to implement the timeout:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor

# ...
def connectionMade(self):
    # ... your code
    # cancel connection in 2 minutes
    reactor.callLater(120, self.transport.loseConnection)
```

Or

> At the end of timeout I just want to discard packet if full packet is not received while connection remains alive.

If you don't want to cancel the connection on timeout then:

```
from time import time as timer

def connectionMade(self):
    # ... your code
    self.endtime = timer() + 120 # timeout in 2 minutes

def dataReceived(self, data):
    if timer() > self.endtime: # timeout
       if not self.have_we_received_full_packet()
          return # do nothing (discard data, the connection remains alive)
       else: 
          # timeout happened but we have a full packet, now what?
    inputArray = bytearray(data)
    #do something
```

Comment: This reactor.callLater() works across connections. What should we do if we need for per connection basis?

Comment: @Arockia what do you think self.transport.loseConnection() does?

Comment: I understand that it terminates the current connection.